# Gorm + MSSQL = not seeing the association

Tags: sql-server, go

I have two models that are linked via UUID, but for some reason Gorm doesn't see them,

```golang
type PERSON struct {
    PERS_ID            mssql.UniqueIdentifier `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id,omitempty"`
    ORG_ID             mssql.UniqueIdentifier `json:"orgId,omitempty"`
    LAST_NAME          mssql.VarChar          `json:"lastName,omitempty"`
    FIRST_NAME         mssql.VarChar          `json:"firstName,omitempty"`
    MIDDLE_NAME        mssql.VarChar          `json:"middleName,omitempty"`
    TAB_NUM            mssql.VarChar          `json:"tabNum,omitempty"`
    SCH_ID             mssql.UniqueIdentifier `json:"schId,omitempty"`
    PRIMARY_IDENTIFIER mssql.UniqueIdentifier `json:"primaryIdentifier,omitempty"`
    TYPE_ID            mssql.UniqueIdentifier `json:"typeId,omitempty"`
    ORG                Organization           `gorm:"foreignKey:ORG_ID;references:ORG_ID" json:"organization"`
}
type Organization struct {
    ORG_ID    mssql.UniqueIdentifier `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id,omitempty"`
    ORG_NAME  mssql.VarChar          `json:"name,omitempty" `
    ORG_DESC  mssql.VarChar          `json:"desc,omitempty"`
    PARENT_ID mssql.UniqueIdentifier `json:"ParentId"`
    LEVEL     int                    `json:"level"`
    SCH_ID    mssql.UniqueIdentifier `json:"schId"`
}
```

when you make a request you get null instead of a relation

I tried a different style of writing fields (which did not work), but if you manually drive in, then the search goes

```golang
var organizations = models.Organization{ORG_ID: person.ORG_ID}
models.DbParsec3.First(&organizations)
```